# Lenovo ThinkPad X200 Tablet restarts randomly

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, restart, tablet

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Lenovo ThinkPad X200 Tablet. It restarts occasionally all of a sudden. I have taken it to a Lenovo service centre. They seem to have found no hardware faults. I did a memtest for RAM overnight and it came out perfect. I need to find out what is causing these restarts. How do I do that?

The restarts really are truly random. I am working solely on AC power. I have removed the battery. This has significantly reduced the restarts, but it still happens. I also considered if it is because the computer is overheating. That was ruled out because sometimes this happens just after it boots up.

The restarts are not bothersome enough to buy a new laptop nor are they too occasional to not consider it.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! Please search this site for questions regarding random reboots and shut-downs. Have you checked the processor temperature?

Comment: Thank you for inviting Jos. I have searched quite extensively over the past few months. I am now here on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are the restarts truly "random"?

I generally avoid laptops because I tend to do CPU heavy things like compiling source code, transcoding video, or light gaming which can sometimes tax the ingrated video chipsets on many laptops.

In nearly all of my experience with laptops, I came to find that I could usually hear my fans spin on before the "random" poweroffs.

Systems are generally designed to power off when they reach high temperatures to avoid damaging the processors, the thermal paste on them, or the board they're seated on.

Comment: They really are truly random. I am working solely on AC power. I have removed the battery. This has significantly reduced the restarts but it still happens. I also considered if it is because the computer is getting heated up. That was ruled out because sometimes this happens just after it boots up.

The restarts are not bothersome enough to buy a new laptop nor are they too occasional to not consider it